# Wanting to make a frosted-glass dry erase whiteboard

Tags: glass

I want a frosted white glass dry erase board for my office. I can hardly find anybody who offers this without 'call us for prices'. I figured it can't be too difficult to make?

1. Purchase sheet of glass (from where?)
2. Cover the back with frosted spray paint or film
3. Drill through the glass about 1-2" off from each corner
4. Mount using mirror type of mounts

Any advice, suggestions or know of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could just ask almost any glass shop to cut and drill the glass for you.

That said, I'd probably want to use tempered glass for this and you can't drill tempered glass so you may want to come up with a different method for mounting.

Comment: +1: Good point about the glass shop having the capability to do it. And if they screw up, it's not the buyer that will have to pay for the broken glass. I meant to mention as well that the average Joe wouldn't be able to work with tempered glass, but of course I left that out of my answer. :)

Comment: Good call. Somebody wanted $1001 for this pre-assembled. I found the tempered glass, manufactured with holes for $140.

Answer (score 6):

I've used [Artscape window film](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=artscape&hl=en&prmd=ivns&biw=1461&bih=845&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=12623366828276632021&sa=X&ei=qWisTeS3D8ry0gG00pz5CA&ved=0CH8Q8wIwBw#) with great results. From what I remember, you just cut the film to size and use a squeegee and water with a bit of soap to adhere it to the glass. I'm not sure if they have a solid frosted pattern though. You'll most likely want to find a sheet big enough that you won't have any seams.

One alternative to drilling holes for standoffs is to get edge-mounted standoffs like [these](http://www.dkhardware.com/product-5653-eg38bs-brushed-stainless-edge-grip-for-3-8-material.html):

[image]

Otherwise, if you like the look of something like [this](http://www.gordonglassusa.com/item/LPC114BS/crl-brushed-stainless-low-profile-standoff-cap-assembly-for-1-1-4-standoff-bases-LPC114BS.htm?src=froogle) (note, you'll have to buy the bases separately) better, use [carbide drill bits](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=202242753&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&ci_sku=202242753&ci_src=14110944&cm_mmc=shopping-_-googlebase-_-D25X-_-202242753&locStoreNum=804) specifically for glass cutting. Make sure you've got plenty of support for the glass sheet. Make sure you're far enough away from the edge - I'd leave no less than 1" between the edge and the hole. Start on one side and drill partway through. Stop before you reach the other side and flip the glass over. Drill through from the backside to avoid chipping or cracking the glass.

Comment: I see no reason to drill it and agree, just use one of the mirror mounts. The only difference is having it 1/2 or 3/4" off the wall looks really sharp, and gives it some depth. Many mirror mounts are designed to hold the mirror essentially flat against the wall, with no space, which will ruin part of the effect a nice glass whiteboard gives.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why that wouldn't work. Although I would avoid drilling through the glass. Find a way to mount it that doesn't require cutting or drilling.

You can buy some glass at big box hardware stores. To get a big sheet, or a custom size, google "glass" plus the name of your city. There are lots of shops set up to provide glass at various thicknesses at just about any size. These are the folks that cut the glass for all the giant windows you see in shops downtown and at the mall.